# Calculating overlap (and distance measures) for categorical variables in R

Tags: r, distance, categorical-data

I am trying to calculate distance between rows (data points) on the basis of categorical variables in columns. The simplest method I have seen is to calculate the overlap. In other words in what proportion of variables do x and y take identical values.

Imagine I have a dataset as follows;

```
    Id = 1:5
    dummy <- data.frame(Country = c("UK", "UK", "USA", "USA", "USA"),
                        Category = c("Private", "Public", "Private", "Private", "Public"),
                        Level = c("High", "Low", "Low", "Low", "High"))
```

and I want to calculate the proportional overlap (as above) between all pairs of rows.

I could define a function to do this;

```
    calcOverlap <- function(Id, df) {
      n <- length(Id)
      results <- matrix(NA, n, n)
      for(i in 1:n) {
        for(j in 1:n) {
          if(i > j) {
            results[i, j] <- length(which(df[i,] == df[j,])) / ncol(df)
          }
        }
      }
      results
    }
```

i think it worked....

```
    dummy
    calcOverlap(Id, dummy)
```

My question is, has this already been implemented more neatly and more generally somewhere. Also more generally, is there a package to calculate distance measures from categorical variables.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way to do it:

```
outer(seq(nrow(DF)), seq(nrow(DF)), Vectorize(function(x,y) mean(DF[x,]==DF[y,])))

          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 1.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
[2,] 0.3333333 1.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
[3,] 0.3333333 0.3333333 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.3333333
[4,] 0.3333333 0.3333333 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.3333333
[5,] 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 1.0000000
```

However, this computes more comparisons than is needed. To avoid that, there's `combn`:

```
# values
v = combn(seq(nrow(DF)), 2, function(x) mean(DF[x[1],]==DF[x[2],]))

# [1] 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 1.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333

# row combos
r = combn(seq(nrow(DF)), 2)
#          [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1    2    2    2    3    3     4
# [2,]    2    3    4    5    3    4    5    4    5     5
```

If you want those in a matrix, there's

```
m = matrix(,nrow(DF),nrow(DF))
m[t(r)] <- v

#      [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
# [1,]   NA 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
# [2,]   NA        NA 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
# [3,]   NA        NA        NA 1.0000000 0.3333333
# [4,]   NA        NA        NA        NA 0.3333333
# [5,]   NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
```

Comment: thank you, wasn't aware of  `combn()`. thanks for taking the time to answer. do you know if there are implementations of other distance measures for categorical variables?

Comment: @user3115675 If you look at `?dist`, you'll see a variety of different methods. It looks to me like none of those would apply to categorical variables. However, scrolling down, some packages are mentioned under "See Also" that may be helpful.